# How to know wether Intel SGX DCAP is installed

Tags: sgx

How should I know if Intel SGX DCAP is installed or not? the server is running ubuntu 20.4.
Is there a way to check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

```
apt list --installed | grep dcap
```

You should see something like this:

```
sgx-dcap-pccs/unknown,now 1.16.100.2-focal1 amd64 [installed]
```

Answer (score 1):

SGX driver should be already installed on >5.11 Linux Kernel, while DCAP is supported by >8th generation Intel processors, as well as Flexible Launch Control. This is how you check:

```
╰─➤  ls -ltr /dev/sgx*
     crw------- 1 root root    10, 124 Oct  3 16:30 /dev/sgx_vepc
     crw-rw---- 1 root sgx_prv 10, 126 Oct  3 16:30 /dev/sgx_provision
     crw-rw---- 1 root sgx     10, 125 Oct  3 16:30 /dev/sgx_enclave

     /dev/sgx:
     total 0
     lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Oct  3 16:30 provision -> ../sgx_provision
     lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Oct  3 16:30 enclave -> ../sgx_enclave
```

Comment: which line indicates DCAP?